# JQuery get next month and year

Tags: jquery, date, printing, future

JQuery - Need to get next month and year

```
Input: January-2017
Input: i=50
```

Output:

```
for(int i=1; i<=50; i++){

  // i=1 print: January-2017
  // i=2 print: February-2017
....
  // i=13 print: January-2018
...
  // i=50 print: ....
}
```

Input may not be January-2017 always. May start with any month and year.
Thanks.

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery and moment.js you can do that like below:

```
function calendar(count, date) {
  var mo = moment(date, 'MMMM-YYYY');
  for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    var next;
    if (i > 1) {
      next = mo.add(1, 'M').format('MMMM-YYYY');
    } else {
      next = mo.format('MMMM-YYYY');
    }
    console.log(next);
  }
}
```

And call it like this: `calendar(50, 'January-2017');`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbz4x79n/)

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you could do it:

1. Use a date library to create the first date and add a month for each item in the loop outputting the date.
2. Create a 12 member array with the months and then use modulus something like:

   ```
   var months = ["January","February", "March"];
   var startYear = 2017;

   for(var i=1; i<=50; i++){
    print(months[((i-1)%12), (Math.Floor(i/12) + startYear);
   }
   ```